# How to read data from DataReader to an custom object without looping over

Tags: c#, ado.net

I know we can read data from SqlDataReader using `While` or `ForEach`, but i was wondering is there any way to fetch the data without looping over?

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        var myString = rdr.GetString(0);
          //put values into a list customized objectt
        listDeclaredElsewhere.Add(myString);
    }
}
```

Is it a good practice to loop over the data to get the values into the list of customized objects ? Or is there any other clean way to do this ?

Comment: Not sure why you think that looping might not be clean way of retrieving data. This of data reader as an array of rows, the cleanest (and fastest) way of getting each row would be looping. Also have a look at the official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: I agree with @peeyushsingh why do you think looping is bad?

Comment: @peeyushsingh, consider i am getting lots of data from the procedure in that case looping over will affect the performance as it will loop each row. is it true?

Comment: Getting lots of data in one go (instead of streaming the data) might effect performance, but once the data is in memory looping should not have impact on performance. Looping is a basic construct and there is nothing negative about it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with looping. I also recommend you use await rdr.ReadAsync()